# Powershell's pipe to program using scanf

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, pipe, scanf

Recently I moved from Windows' cmd.exe to PowerShell. Later on I discovered that Microsoft decided to abandon standard stdin redirection method `abc.exe < input.txt` and recommends using `Get-Content input.txt | .\abc.exe`.

Unfortunately new method crashed my app. I created this simple program to find the source of the problem

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int x = -1;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;
}
```

and discovered that this test program returns -1 instead of number inside input.txt.

I also tested commands like `echo 1 | .\abc.exe` and `type input.txt | .\abc.exe` and all of them print -1 to stdout.

I would be grateful for any help.

**Edit 1:**

Result of $OutputEncoding command:

```
IsSingleByte      : True                                  
BodyName          : us-ascii                              
EncodingName      : US-ASCII                              
HeaderName        : us-ascii                              
WebName           : us-ascii                              
WindowsCodePage   : 1252                                  
IsBrowserDisplay  : False                                 
IsBrowserSave     : False                                 
IsMailNewsDisplay : True                                  
IsMailNewsSave    : True                                  
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True                                  
CodePage          : 20127
```

**Edit 2:**

I created this simple program to see what is piped to program:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {

    char l;
    while(scanf("%c", &l)) {
        printf("%d\n", l);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After running `Get-Content input.txt | .\abc.exe` it keeps printing 10 which corresponds to ASCII "line feed" character.

Comment: Show value of `$OutputEncoding` in PowerShell. Also rewrite native application to read char by char and print read codes, so to know what exactly got piped to it.

Comment: Your **Edit 2** program does not stop on `EOF` and keeps printing last character. It should be `while(scanf("%c", &l)!=EOF)`. I also compile your first test program and it work fine for me. I type: `echo 12345 | .\test.exe`, and it print `12345`.

Comment: Lately I've been messing with PowerShell in order to make Python display Unicode characters properly in console (example: `print "ąę"` resulted with ae in console). While doing this I've found solution to add these lines `[Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`,
`[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` to PS profile configuration. As the result additional bytes were received by scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently PowerShell has multiple places where encoding needs to be set before everything starts to work fine.

Finally I came up with this solution - add lines that are below this text to your PS profile file:

```
[Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
chcp 1250 // Change here for preferable Windows Code Page. 1250 is Central Europe
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
Clear-Host // clear screen because chcp prints text "Active code page: (code page)"
```

After including these lines `Get-Content` started to behave correctly.